# How can an NGO ensure secure mobile communication between HQ and their delegates in the field?

Tags: encryption, smartphone

I work for an NGO that does engineering projects in several developing countries. Our delegates who are doing the field work are for the most part not very tech-savvy, i. e. they wouldn't know how to set up GPG properly. We are rather small and don't have the possibility to provide a VPN connection. They do have their own smartphones and laptops with them.

How can we ensure secure, encrypted communication with our delegates in the field? An example would be secure submission of test results.

Comment: @Eekhon Look at this https://crypto.cat/

Comment: password protected zip files are pretty simple to use.

Comment: "Secure" really needs to define **secure against whom** or against what type of threat. Security isn't a binary property, it's a continuum along multiple axis.

Answer (score 4):

`and don't have the possibility to provide a VPN connection`

What has size (or budget) got to do with it? Both Android and iPhones (and many more mobile devices including Laptops running MSWindows, Linux of MacOS) provide PPTP, L2TP and IPSEC out of the box. They will also happily connect to HTTPS services.

The "server" end only needs an accessible IP address, a physical device and some software. And you must already have the first 2 if you are providing services such as email.

However if good rather than basic security is required then you should be looking at delivering a remote desktop type service - just delivering the display to the device - since you can't assure the physical security of the device, you cannot trust its integrity.

Trying to lock down the device, remotely manage it and maintain an encrypted filesystem is a common approach for enterprises (and required if you are going to maintain sensitive data on the device) but this is where the costs escalate even faster than the attack surface. A further issue is that this a BYOD model - why should you have control over a device not owned by you.

IMHO providing secure access to a centrally hosted user interface is more secure and cheaper. It also solves the ownership issue of BYOD.